# MS Access SubForm - ODBC Call Failed changing "LinkFields" in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

In our MS Access database, we have a subform that has one RecordSource but we change how the data is displayed in it by updating the "LinkMasterFields" and "LinkChildFields" properties in VBA.

For example, the link fields by default will be as follows:

```
Me.subfrmOurSubForm.LinkMasterFields = "Field1;Field2"
Me.subfrmOurSubForm.LinkChildFields = "Field1;Field2"
```

We then give the user the option to change how the data in displayed in the subform by running VBA code:

```
Me.subfrmOurSubForm.LinkMasterFields = "Field3;Field2"
Me.subfrmOurSubForm.LinkChildFields = "Field3;Field2"
```

This code worked flawlessly when we were using Access tables but since we migrated over the SQL Server and now have OBDC linked tables, we are getting the following VBA Run-time error when trying to run the code above:

```
ODBC--call failed.
```

If this is a limitation in Access, that is fine, we can live with it. However, we'd rather not create anymore subforms objects than we have to. Has anyone found a way around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen troubles changing the *count* of the fields.

To not alter the count, duplicate the field name:

```
Me.subfrmOurSubForm.LinkMasterFields = "Field3;Field3"
Me.subfrmOurSubForm.LinkChildFields = "Field3;Field3"
```

Comment: My apologies, I did not key my code in our question correctly. Yes, we are aware of that and our code does handle that. The error is still thrown with the logic you gave in your answer.

Comment: OK. I haven't seen this behaviour, but would say it should not happen. You could try using another (newer native) ODBC driver or, perhaps, replace the semicolon separator with comma.